What is the English original of this translated essay of V. N. Bhatkhande's?
The multilingual भातखण्डे स्मृति ग्रन्थ / Bhatkhande Commemoration Volume, issued to mark the birth centenary of the great scholar, theoretician, and teacher of North Indian classical music, includes several of his previously uncollected or unpublished essays. One such is आधुनिक हिन्दुस्तानी राग-पद्धति एवं उसके अध्ययनकरने की सरलतम विधि / "The current Hindustani raga system and the simplest method for its study," found on pages 493–517 of the pdf (pp. 427–451 of the original book). At the end of the essay, there is a note that says मूलत: अंग्रेजी से अनुवादित / "Translated from the original English." The translator is identified as Amaresh Chandra Chaubey from Khairagarh. However, no bibliographic information is provided about the original English version of this essay.
Since the essay begins देवियों एवं सज्जनों / "Ladies and Gentlemen," it evidently was a speech Bhatkhande delivered somewhere. What was the occasion for the speech? Is the original English version of the speech available anywhere in print or (preferably) online?
Reference
Bhatkhande, Vishnu Narayan. "aadhunik hindustani raag-paddhati eva.m usake adhyayan_karne kii saralattam vidhi." Translated from the original English by Amaresh Chandra Chaubey. bhaat_khaNDe smR^iti granth / Bhatkhande Commemoration Volume. Khairagarh, India: Indira Kala Sangeet Vishwavidyalaya, 1966. pp. 427–451. Accessed from archive.org December 30, 2023.
